# Waiting for multiple threads start, started() not caught

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to write a barrier-like synchronization primitive for Qt that ensures several threads are started at certain point. However, I seem to run into situation when I don't get signals (e.g. started()) working for me.

I tried to shrink a code to compile a minimal (non-)working example.

```
========
main.cpp
========
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "qmultithreadwaiter.hpp"
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <qdebug.h>

#define dlog qDebug()

class Test: public QThread {

public:
   virtual void run( ) {
      QThread::sleep( 500 );
   }
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) {
   QCoreApplication a( argc, argv );
   Test t1, t2;
   QMultiThreadWaiter w;
   w.addThread(1, &t1);
   w.addThread(2, &t2);

   t1.start();
   t2.start();

   w.wait4all();
   dlog << "Wait completed";

   return 0;
}

=========================
qmultithreadwaiter.hpp
=========================    
// Qt includes
#include <QSignalMapper>
#include <QMap>
#include <QThread>

class QMultiThreadWaiter: public QThread {
Q_OBJECT

   QMap < int, bool > started;
   QSignalMapper sm;

private slots:
   void threadStarted( int id );
   void someThreadStarted();

signals:
   void allStarted( );

public:
   QMultiThreadWaiter( );

   void addThread( int id, QThread* t );
   void wait4all( );

};
=================
qmultithreadwaiter.cpp
=================
#include "qmultithreadwaiter.hpp"

// Qt includes
#include <QThread>
// Debug includes
#include <qdebug.h>

#define dlog qDebug()

// Project includes

void QMultiThreadWaiter::threadStarted( int id ) {
   dlog << "Thread #" << id << " started!";
   started[ id ] = true;
   QMapIterator < int, bool > mi( started );
   while ( mi.hasNext( ) ) {
      mi.next( );
      if ( !mi.value( ) )
         return;
   }

   dlog << "All threads started!";

   // All threads are started
   emit allStarted( );
}

void QMultiThreadWaiter::addThread( int id, QThread* t ) {
   dlog << "Adding thread " << t << " with id " << id;
   sm.setMapping( t, id );
   connect( t, SIGNAL(started()), &sm, SLOT(map()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
   connect( t, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(someThreadStarted()),
            Qt::QueuedConnection );
}
void QMultiThreadWaiter::wait4all( ) {
   dlog << "Starting this thread";
   start( );
   dlog << "Going to wait";
   wait( );
   dlog << "Wait finished";
}

QMultiThreadWaiter::QMultiThreadWaiter( ) {
   sm.moveToThread( this );
   connect( &sm, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(threadStarted(int)),
            Qt::QueuedConnection );
   connect( this, SIGNAL(allStarted()), this, SLOT(quit()),
            Qt::QueuedConnection );
   connect( this, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT( someThreadStarted()),
            Qt::QueuedConnection );
}

void QMultiThreadWaiter::someThreadStarted( ) {
   dlog << "Some thread started!";
}
```

Output:

```
Adding thread  QThread(0x28fefc)  with id  1 
Adding thread  QThread(0x28fef4)  with id  2 
Starting this thread 
Going to wait
<stuck>
```

What is strange is that even `someThreadStarted()` is not called for `this`. Please, advise.

Comment: I think that `started()` signal is only emmited when you use eventloop inside your thread. Otherwise it won't be emmited. Put `exec()` in your run method and check if signal is emmited.

Answer (score 0):

None of your threads have an event loop running. When you call `w.wait4all();` from your `main()`, the main thread blocks when execution reaches `wait()`. Using `Qt::QueuedConnection` to connect your signals means that your slots will be called when the control on the target thread goes back to the event loop, which is never for your test threads. Meanwhile, your main thread is blocked at `wait()`, and also lacks an event loop (`QCoreApplication::exec()` is never called). The main thread also cannot process the queued signals it receives, which is why the `this` thread also doesn't seem to emit `started()`.